# What is a "constant fraction" of a total?

Tags: fractions, constants

What is it mean to say that some quantity is a "constant fraction" of another quantity?

Comment: The two quantities may change, but their **ratio** remains constant. As I drink my beer, the amount of liquid in the bottle changes, but the amount of alcohol left in the bottle is a constant fraction of the amount of liquid left in the bottle.

Comment: @André: If you drink the entire thing, the alcohol content becomes zero and vacuously it grows and shrinks at the same time. So either you never finish your beer, or you have an infinite bottle of beer.

Comment: Cantor drank half, then half of what remained, and then half of what remained, and so on. Then (the stroke of genius) he had another beer, and the ordinals were born.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that $f(x)$ is a constant fraction of $g(x)$ means the same thing as being a constant multiple of $g(x)$ -- just written as $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{c}$ instead of $f(x)=cg(x)$.

In either case, the key is that $c$ does not depend on $x$... that is, the relation holds for every $x$.

Comment: So, how should I interpret the following statement: "Algorithm A achieves a constant fraction of the accuracy of algorithm B"?

Comment: You can think of the accuracy of an algorithm as a function of its input.  Say the input is $X$, the accuracy of algorithm $A$ on input $X$ is $\epsilon_A(X)$, and the accuracy of algorithm $B$ on input $X$ is $\epsilon_B(X)$. I would say that this means there is a constant $c$, independent of $X$, such that $\epsilon_A(x)=\frac{1}{c}\epsilon_B(x)$.

Comment: @madpuppet (Or, more likely for the context, I would probably interpret it as "at least a constant fraction of the accuracy"; replace "$=$" by "$\geq$".)